# How to Add Product ID Search Functionality to Python Word Counter and Display Associated Words?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk, text-processing

I have a very large list of Movie Reviews. This is my schema sample...it's about 4000 rows, so there's a lot going on.

| MovieID | FreeformComment |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | This was a great movie it made me happy |
| 5678 | This movie was bad, I hated it |
| 5678 | This movie was decent |

Below is my Python script - what it does is give me a total word count for all of the reviews, as well as another count of phrases to try and get more context...i.e. ('scary', 'loved') if they both loved the movie and it was scary. Or ('short', 'value') if the movie was too short and they did not feel they got their money's worth. The script writes a new Excel doc with the counts.

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from collections import Counter
import string
from nltk.util import ngrams

nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('stopwords')

lemmatizer = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()

df = pd.read_excel('svydata.xlsx')

comments_df = df["Movie Review Comment"].astype(str)
comments = ' '.join(comments_df)

tokenized_words = nltk.word_tokenize(comments)

translator = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
tokenized_words = [word.lower() for word in tokenized_words]
tokenized_words = [word.translate(translator) for word in tokenized_words]

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
filtered_words = [word for word in tokenized_words if word not in stop_words]

lemmatized_words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in filtered_words]

max_phrase_length = 3  # Adjust as needed
phrases = [phrase for n in range(2, max_phrase_length + 1) for phrase in ngrams(lemmatized_words, n)]

word_counter = Counter(lemmatized_words)
phrase_counter = Counter(phrases)

sorted_word_counter = sorted(word_counter.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)

sorted_phrase_counter = sorted(phrase_counter.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)

word_df = pd.DataFrame(sorted_word_counter, columns=['Word', 'Count'])
phrase_df = pd.DataFrame(sorted_phrase_counter, columns=['Phrase', 'Count'])

with pd.ExcelWriter('word_and_phrase_counts.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    word_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Top Words', index=False)
    phrase_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Top Phrases (2-5 words)', index=False)
```

The issue is I want to put this into a data visualization where I can select a Movie ID filter and then see the word count for only comments regarding that movie i.e. The most common word for movie 1234 was 'great' and the most common phrase was ('loved', 'acting'), or something like that.

The issue is I need to somehow join this based on the MovieID. There isn't really a clean way to do this that requires re-thinking the data architecture. But the data is so large, there aren't tons of options. I'm a beginner and have been trying to find ways around this - would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

I've tried methods to join in Excel, but it's just not sustainable for dashboarding. I've tried methods to make it a matrix but there's too many words and too many reviews.

Comment: I would suggest changing your data structure into long format where you have multiple rows per review (like review ID, word / n-gram, count) and then using a proper visualization tool like Tableau or PowerBI for visualization and building a dashboard.

Comment: Yeah, the visualization tool will be a Tableau/PowerBI type of tool. I think I'm mostly struggling with the data structure change. Can you provide more context into what you mean about multiple rows per review?

Comment: You should have multiple rows per movie review, one word / n-gram and count thereof per row. Data viz tools prefer data "long" format as they do aggregation for you: https://apfa.io/long-data-v-wide-data/

You should also look into using sklearn's CountVectorizer as opposed to using nltk and base python for counting words and computing n-grams as this is much easier.

Comment: Do you see runtime being an issue? Or optimization in general. Again, I'm pretty new to this. i did change to countvectorizer but realized I not only need to group it by MovieID, but RecordID - which is a field I didn't mention that's just the unique identifier of the actual review. Having it grouped by MovieID, WordCnt, Phrase makes the visualization funky. i.e. if I look at the word "great" - I get all the review records of the movie that contains "great" at least once...I get all the other reviews of that movie though, even if it doesn't contain the word. Which seems to be a problem